# Bootstrap 3 Responsive Naviagion Button not Opening

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to create a responsive navigation, but when I in responsive mode it doesn't open it when clicking the button. I'm not sure what is causing this problem. This is new to me, since I haven't had this happen to me before till now.

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/0rzo7y0w/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">Web Page</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you include all the javascript and css? I copy/pasted your code on a file and it works fine.

Comment: Yes. I'm using the CDN version from the bootstrap websit.

Comment: Yes. I'm using the bootstrap version from their website.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap js file as well? You need it for the toogle.

Comment: I did notice I didn't add the JS file-- added it. Still having the same issue.

Comment: I changed the order of the imports on your fiddle, first JQuery, then Bootstrap, and the fiddle works fine. If you check the web console you will see an error, 'Bootstrap needs JQuery...' Check the code below and, if it works, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After including js and css files it should work. The full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">Web Page</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```